# Is there a way to search/export potential duplicates?

Tags: groups, search, export, duplicate-contacts

I'm about to run dedupe (**Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts**) and I was wondering if there is a way to put all potential duplicates from a certain rule into a group so I could export them as a backup before I start merging.

For example, I was hoping the Advanced Search page would have a field to search by dedupe rule but I don't see that type of option. Am I missing it, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way that I am aware of, but you can call the dedupe function in the BAO from an extension?